# How to Flag Floats in a vector of Floats and Chars in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a  mixed vector of floats and characters that I'm streaming from a text file. This vector is being read in as a string. My problem is that I want to parse only the floats and ignore the characters. How can I do this?

```
v = "Float_or_Char"
if isblank(v) == false   # <-- v might be blank as well
    Parse(Float64,v)  # <-- only if v is a Float (how do I do this?)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing `x` is a vector of strings, some of which are floats-as-strings and the rest are actual strings, you could do something like

```
for i in 1:length(x)
    f = NaN
    try
        f = float(x[i])
        println("$i is a float")
    catch
        println("$i isn't a float")
    end
end
```

If you are using Julia 0.4 (not yet released), you could get really fancy if you just wanted the floats from `x` using the new `Nullable` type and the new method `tryparse`

```
maybe_floats = map(s->tryparse(Float64,s), x)
floats = map(get, filter(n->!isnull(n), maybe_floats))
```